# d3.extent() on object keys (not values)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, extent

I have an object that looks like this,

```
{
    "1420165140": 172.52,
    "1420254360": 63.78,
    "1420341900": 141.55,
    "1420422480": 85.8,
    "1421035920": 86.07,
    "1422506820": 118.42
}
```

The keys are epoch time stamps. I would like to extract the max and min dates of the keys using something like this,

```
var  range = d3.extent(d, function(d){ return d.key });
```

I've tried casting `+d.key` to a number from a string.

Unfortunately, all I get back is `[undefined, undefined]`

How can I run [d3.extent](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_extent) on object keys?

Comment: Use [`d3.entries()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_entries).

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Should be [`d3.keys()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_keys), right?

Comment: @altocumulus Can use that as well -- with `d3.entries` the rest of the code (`d.key`) can remain the same.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Wow, good catch! I hadn't thought about that. Nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use it as

```
var range = d3.extent(Object.keys(d));
```

where `d` is your JSON object.